# How to join multiple kafka topics in flink and avoid duplicates

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I have setup an apache flink job and taskmanager, and on my local machine I'm using a sql client connected to flink.

Im trying to join topics.

Lets say I have

```
Topic OrderHeader content (id, customer_number)  
Topic OrderLine content (id, order_header_id, item_number)
```

Now if I create two tables consuming with the connector 'kafka' I am able to create those two tables and create a new table where I insert data into it with a join select.

Like this

```
insert into result_table
select ol.id, ol.item_number, oh.customer_number);
```

But if I have two messages in my OrderHeader topic with the same key then for every order_line that matches those two I get a result as I would if I had done the same in any database.

But I would like to ignore old messages once I get a newer one for the order header.

So I tried changing my orderHeader and orderLine tables to consume with

```
    'connector' = 'upsert-kafka',
```

Now I only have unique rows in those tables (one for each key)

But after doing that my insert using the join fails with this error

> doesn't support consuming update and delete changes which
> is produced by node Join(joinType=[InnerJoin

Can you point me to a best practices way of doing this?

Looking forward to your help
Best regards.
Ole Bille